# How does the weightlifting belt work?

Tags: strength-training

What does a weightlifting belt protects against? How exactly? I can't imagine why wearing it is better, although I have used them and, at least subjectively, I felt more safe and comfortable during the lifts.

Comment: http://breakingmuscle.com/olympic-weightlifting/weightlifting-belts-should-you-use-one-pro-and-con

Comment: http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/lessons-in-weight-belts-how-and-why-to-use-them.html

Comment: http://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/weightbelt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons why you would where a weight belt and the best reason is:

- To protect your lower back.

It depends on what weight you are lifting, if you are lifting something that require some effort then you would need a weight belt.

Please have look at this links with more information.

- All of the upsides to wearing a belt come down to the idea of intra-abdominal force or pressure.
  [Pros and Cons of varying belt.](http://breakingmuscle.com/olympic-weightlifting/weightlifting-belts-should-you-use-one-pro-and-con)
- The assistance and/or protection provided by a support belt during exercise may be a result of increased abdominal pressure (IAP), feedback to the exerciser on body position, reduced compressive and shear forces on the spine, and restricted torso movement. [More.](http://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/weightbelt.html)

Comment: Thanks! Your links above are relevant, because it is there where the answer lies. I think your answer would be much improved if you added them, specially the 1st and 3rd, together with a short comment or a quote about the effect of the belt in reducing intra-abdominal pressure, creating a safer environment for the spine, and giving proprioceptive feedback. Then I would give the green mark with pleasure.

Comment: Agreed. You seem to have a fondness for including links in your answer. Given the nature of the internet, links decay and information is lost. Rather than linking, if you could summarize the important information here as well, then it won't be lost (And make the answer useless) should the linked page disappear.

Comment: @JohnP You are right. That is a problem in general in all SE sites, because usually the linked text is too long to be merely copied in an answer (not to mention the possible copyright issues). That is why I encouraged this user to add a short comment or quoting the most essential part of the text. That is what I try to do as well in my posts. But yes, the problem with the links is always present in all SE sites. Until SE automatically copy the linked pages (similarly to [the internet wayback archive](http://archive.org/web/web.php)) little more than rewriting the texts can be done about it.